# ios5: Launch email from NSObject class while inside another modal view

Tags: email, ios5, modal-dialog, nsobject

I have a common action sheet (in NSObject class) that is called from multiple classes.  One of the actions is launching email.  Everything works great when called from the first NIB loaded.  However, after I switch NIBs using modal views, the email (its own modal view) will not appear in any of these (but all other actions work fine).  I presume it is because they are modal views and not the viewController called by the App's delegate. I presume the "rootViewController" below is the issue.  I'm stuck. Help appreciated.

```
-(void)SendEmail {


// all this NSObject to send emails
rootViewController = (UIViewController*)[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] viewController];

// compose
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
//controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;


//format message
NSArray *recipientsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"support@A___.com", nil];  // email recipients must be in an array
[controller setToRecipients:recipientsArray];
[controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A question about %@",stuff]];
//[controller setMessageBody:outputMutString isHTML:YES];

//send
if (controller) {
    NSLog(@"email controller");
    [rootViewController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

}

Comment: Reading around, this may have to do with delegate patterns.  Perhaps I have to make the present modal view a delegate of rootViewController.  Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've encountered the same issue.